# Are there any apps for storing SMS online for latter viewing and searching?

Tags: sms, storage

I like how Google voice stores all my text messages online so I can search them and store conversations for ever. But I am not a fan of Google voice and want to use my own number etc.

I saw a few apps that upload texts to Gmail but I don't want to clutter my gmail inbox. Any separate apps that are specialized in this?

Comment: ON a side-not most of the apps that upload your texts to GMail (like [SMSBackup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync)) let you select a custom label to put all your texts in and specify whether or not you want them in your inbox. My texts are backed up to Gmail this way, and I never notice them unless I specifically go into the "SMS" lable to look for a specific text.

Answer (score 1):

There are several programs that will allow you to save your texts (among other things) on a computer, like Myphoneexplorer. It depends if you want to be able to access them everywhere, or if having them on one computer is enough for you (you can still do copies/backups of the texts).